# Qthreadpool in Qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv

I am doing some coding with OpenCV and I am processing some image pixel. However, the process take so much time (The picture is very delayed) because I am processing each color R G B on a sequence base. I thought I can make it faster by doing multi-threading and based on my previous knowledge Threadpool is more effecient. I saw some examples on line but they all requiring the use of QRunnable and my implementation should be easier than that because I just want to pass the same function with different channels every time

any idea !!!

Comment: There's nothing complex about QRunnable. You probably just need one implementation of that, that takes parameters so that you specify which channel to process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a function in a separate thread you can use the [`QtConcurrentRun`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtconcurrentrun.html) mechanism.

Suppose you have a function `f` with an integer as argument, in a class `A`

```
class A {
public:
    f(int i);
}
```

Now if you want to call the function asynchronously, from a different class you can do:

```
A a;
QFuture<void> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(a, &A::f, 1); // Call it with argument 1
QFuture<void> future2 = QtConcurrent::run(a, &A::f, 2); // Call it with argument 2
```

You can use [`QFutureWatcher`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfuturewatcher.html) in order to get notified when the execution has finished.

Comment: Thank you I tried it and it worked with a simple multiplication method, but it didn't work with my function I have no idea why!